# Overwrite Magento core functionality

Tags: module, magento-1, custom

How do I properly overwrite Magento core functionality? I want to create a module that does it.

I need to edit this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`

I know there is a option to copy this file to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php` and add my functionality to it which will let Magento read this file from local folder instead of core folder.

It's a easy way of doing but by creating a custom module it's easier to manage all the changes I have done.

---

So here is what I have done so far:

I have created a `/app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml` config file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_CustomPriceRevert>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vendore_CustomPriceRevert>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This is my second file in `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml` and it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

---

I know these two files are essential for any module to work.

Now, what file do I need to create now if I want to overwrite this file? Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: similar to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155945/20064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code inside `<config>` tag in `config.xml` file

```
<global>
    <models>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
     <sales_order_create>MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </models>
</global>
```

then add below code in `MyCompany/MyModule/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php` file

```
<?php
class MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create
{
     echo "Hello World!"; die();
}
```

Comment: Great thank you. In the `config.xml` file does it have to go between `<config>` tags or add new `<global>` tags? I just been reading one tutorial and it was there so just making sure.

Comment: yeah in the `<global>` tag inside `<config>`.forget to mention that.. I updated my answer

Comment: Great! Thanks for your interest. I actually found some tutorial how to do it now. I was searching wrong. In here, I am overwriting Magento `Model` and when I was searching for "How to overwrite Magento functionality there was also `Helpers` etc which got me confused. Anyway, I got  the! Thank you one more!

Comment: You're welcome!